# Does this construction work? "do as many something as someone else does"

Tags: construction

Is it possible to use this construction? Is it correct?

He can provide as many pros as I can provide cons.

I can buy as many things as you can sell.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate Bunting said in her comment, the structures are fine and idiomatic.

You can also delete some material common to the two clauses and say, for instance: "He can provide as many pros as I can cons."

The two things compared should be broadly similar because of the inherent meaning of "as."  You can say: "He speaks Greek as well as I speak Latin" to compare language ability; however, you would not say: "He speaks Greek as well as I can ski," except as a kind of joke.  The abilities are not normally comparable by any common standard.